# How to NOT reset Bootstrap Carousel slides

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using the Bootstrap Carousel as header of a website in PHP, is there any way to keep the memory of the slide reached when I change the page of my website? So in the next page it would start with the next slide and not from the start again.

Feel free to ask me for detailed parts, I have just put the standard carousel code in each page at the top (including one PHP file).

**Update1**: Thank you for the answer, I've created a session in order to save which slide the carousel should start with. Now the question is: how I can get the current slide number? (because the carousel cycles after x seconds and I need to get the last slide showed).

**Solved**: @Andrea Ajek thank you very much for the answer! It solved my question also without using PHP sessions!!

Comment: This is a fairly vague question and you may get downvoted for that reason, just so you know. Back on subject, you could do this by setting the latest viewed slide in user's session, cookie, or local storage. Then pick up where you left off by checking that value on another page.

Comment: put an event listener on `slid.bs.carousel` event and store the latest slide number in the cookie

Comment: The proper way to do this is to NOT reload the header part of your page and just replace the page content using asynchronous calls, also updating the address using `pushstate`. If you do it any other way, the slider will be reloaded, re-rendered, and re-initialized, eventually starting from the slide it was on when you navigated. The simplest way to go is using $_SESSION storage to remember the current slide, every time it changes. When you get to a new page, check what slide you were on and `init()` from that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 WebStorage to save the last slide index. Assuming that your carousel has an id attribute equal to "myCarousel", this code should work flawlessly:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var currentSlide = $('#myCarousel div.active').index();
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastSlide', currentSlide);
});
```

The event 'slid.bs.carousel' occurs when the carousel has finished sliding from one item to another. To check if there is a slide index stored in sessionStorage and initialize correctly the carousel, you can use the following code:

```
if(sessionStorage.lastSlide){
      $("#myCarousel").carousel(sessionStorage.lastSlide*1);
}
```